# What does the word 'plotting' mean in this review title?

Tags: meaning

From a software application review:

> Tic-Tac-Toe Becomes A True Challenge Again With This Plotting Puzzler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The review at [toucharcade.com](http://toucharcade.com/2013/12/02/tic-tactics-review-tic-tac-toe-becomes-a-true-challenge-again-with-this-plotting-puzzler/) of Tic-Tactics uses the word *[plotting](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plotting)* to mean scheming, or using strategy.  Some sentences from the review make this clear:

> Tic-Tactics ... injects ... a chance for strategy that looks simple but can be more complex than it appears. ...
>   It has a unique strategy element that looks deceptively simple but offers a quite complex system of strategies and moves depending on how far you can think ahead. It's one of those rare strategy games that anyone can pick up and play and find an infinite number of ways to tackle its challenge ...

Comment: Thank you! Can it also refer here to putting points on a graph? This game is played on a kind of a grid.

Comment: @WineBuG, yes, that probably was intended as a secondary (less important) meaning, but it's likely that both meanings are intended.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a clever pun, implying the double meaning of the aforementioned scheming, or using strategy, as well as marking a location on a graph.